# How does artificial confluence of rivers differ from natural confluence of rivers?

Tags: scripture, belief, culture, rivers

The AP Government [linked](http://www.ndtv.com/india-news/godawari-krishna-inter-linking-of-two-massive-rivers-is-a-dream-come-true-1218426) rivers Krishna and Godavari by artificial means. Given that;

1. What does this artificial confluence mean according to Hinduism? Does it signify anything in religious or spiritual perspective?
2. How does it differ from a natural confluence such as [Triveni Sangam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triveni_Sangam)?

Comment: Just for Info MP govt has done the same with kshipra and narmada in Ujjain.